# Show images and play videos without allowing copying, or downloading

Tags: php, jquery, html, image, video

Is there any way to display images and / or videos on a website and not allow visitors to download or copy them?

I once saw a website where I tried to download an image, but then it was impossible to open it on my computer because the file type was not recognized on my computer!

Is there any way to encode the files, maybe?

Thank you all.

Comment: No. For them to be displayed on the client machine they *have* to be downloaded to the client machine, usually in the Temp folder. There is no way to stop users saving your content to their machines, and any attempt to do so is a waste of time. If you don't want content stolen, don't put it online, or watermark it.

Comment: No there is not. You can obfuscate it, but you cannot prevent people from keeping it. There are dumb hacks to try and make noobs who are not technically inclined not figure it out, but anyone who understands basic javascript, html, and how the network tab works can steal anything you send to them whether you like it or not.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers :)

Answer (score 1):

If you can show the images and videos in a browser, they will always find a way to copy these. You can't have the cake and eat it.

The only thing you can do is to make it harder for the newbie.

Comment: I also didn't downvote, but the answer lacks an explanation on why it is not possible (as given in the first comment to the question).

Comment: @BDL: When I say it is always possible to copy the file, and I said why, I no longer need to prove it is impossible to protect it. Do I?

Comment: Yes, but you are not saying why it is not possible. You say "It is not possible.". But what would be good is "It is not possible because XYZ". "They will always find a way to copy it" is not a reason. " they are downloaded to the client machine, usually in the Temp folder to display them" is a reason.

Comment: @BDL: OK, I understand what you mean. Well the pictures need not to be written on a temporary folder, but are downloaded with http or https protocol into the memory of the browser. Every http(s) request issued by the browser in order to display the pictures can be issued by another utility like *wget* or *curl*, a *perl* or *php* piece of code to download these.